# Citing a Foreign Patent--How do include a copy?

Tags: prior-art, patent-applications

So I'm including a foreign patent in my Information Disclosure Statement (IDS), and my resources tell me I need to include a copy of non-US patents.  How do I do that?  I plan to file via efs-web.  I tried from Google Patents downloading the PDF, but it was in German.  Am I making this harder than it needs to be?

Comment: Why not include the german copy?

Comment: @DonQuiKong Won't they expect me to include a copy in english?  It's available via Google Patents, I just don't know how to get a pdf (or whatever) file of it to include in my filing.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure they won't expect an English copy. Imagine foreign filers translating documents from foreign search reports .. no way ;). www.espacenet.com for a PDF. (I'm not sure you even need to include a copy, but I don't know, better safe than sorry I guess)